# How can I assign a default value to a SharePoint 2010 column assigned to Lookup?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint 2010 site  and have there a column assigned to a Lookup.
Can I assign a **default value** to the column?

Answer (score 1):

We can use PowerShell script to set default value to lookup column.

```
$web= Get-SPWeb http://sp2010
$list = $web.Lists["CustomList"]
$listField = $list.Fields["TestLookup"]
$listField.DefaultValue = "1"
$listField.Update()
```

Or using Infopath to achieve it.

**Article**: [SharePoint 2010 - Set default value for a lookup column using InfoPath and no code](http://kenkumar.blogspot.com/2011/06/sharepoint-2010-set-default-value-for.html)

If you want to set default value to lookup column in client side, we can use CSOM with PowerShell to achieve it.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

$url="http://sp2010"
$userName="administrator"
$password="**"
$domain="test"
$listName="CustomList"
$fieldName="TestLookup"

$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)  
$credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($userName,$password,$domain)   
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials

$list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
$field = $list.Fields.GetByTitle($fieldName)

$field.DefaultValue = "1"
$field.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Thank you for the PowerShell script sample.
Could you please - it may be run on any computer; not necessarily on the SharePoint server?

I have never run any PowerShell scipt of that type (about SharePoint)

Comment: I modify the reply, check it. Using CSOM with PowerShell to achieve it.